# How to stop build a bot from automatically making a new bot for my application

Tags: discord

When creating a new bot in discord via developer portal... Bot Token is already created. There is no "click to reveal token" as the bot is automticaly created and supposedly shown even before I have clicked onto the "bot" page via UI for the 'FIRST TIME'. Why is it making a bot token automticly as I have never seen it to begin with. I tried making more apllictaions all have the same result I would have to chnage the token via the code but why is "build-a-bot" doing and creating it despite me not even creating one it was already done and I havent seen the token yet.

Also i tried CRTL SIFT I it only brings up the inbox nothing else. I reinstalled DISCORD VIA PTB client still nothing. And how do I get into the bot directory?

I tried testing and creating more. But all had the same result

Comment: as soon as you create a bot in the build a bot page it shows you the token immediately for you to copy and then you cant view it again the only way you can is by pressing reset token and obtaining a new bot token

Comment: if I make a new application the "build-a-bot" page is already done before I have  done anything kind of silly that it is already done and the website assumes I already have the code. have to reset it each time.

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that can you share a screenshot or recording of what happens?

Comment: https://youtu.be/dAimNXSNVa4 here

Comment: It seems Discord changed it to now automatically create the bot and now have to reset the token to obtain it for the first time, very weird update might I add